# How to disable refreshing title with live updates?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Below results from [`dcc.Interval`](https://dash.plotly.com/live-updates); how to rid of the "Updating..." and fix it at "Title"?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize it via the `update_title` argument of the `Dash` object. To disable it completely,

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__, update_title=None)
```

For details, see [the documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/external-resources). Note that the feature was introduced in Dash v1.14.0.

Comment: Introduced three days ago - just in time for this question.